# SQL Server : Mapping table design

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, mapping

I have 2 tables, Table A and Table B which have the following structure:

[image: Table A:]

and

[image: Table B]

There is a 1-1 relationship between tables identified by `Product_group` in `Table A` and `<campaign_month,campaign>` in `Table B`.

For example, `‘ 1808 Product - Group 3a’ = <’201808’,‘group_3a’>.`

I am trying to create a mapping table using Tables A and B which should contain 3 columns, namely, `<Product_group, campaign_month, campaign>.`

Since I am not able to join the two tables, I am looking for other ways of creating the mapping table.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is the format of Product_group consistent?  If so then you can create a CTE that reformats the columns of Table A to match the formats of Table B.  Then you can join the CTE to Table B and obtain the result.

Comment: In your example there are two <201808’,‘group_3a> in table_b. Is there a preference to use the first record<111,201808,'group_3a'> and not the second one<115,'201808','group_3a'> for mapping with '1808 Product - Group 3a'

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph Every Product_group will have one entry in the mapping table, so both record<111,201808,'group_3a'> and <115,'201808','group_3a'> should be mapped to the same product_group from table A which is '1808 Product - Group 3a'.

Comment: @JohnTamburo Yes, as far as I know product group is consistent. However, I do see some entries in Table A like `‘ 1809 Product - Group 1c - Test1’` for which I do not have a corresponding 
`group_1c-Test1` as campaign in Table B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following, I am joining the two tables on the basis of whether the string in campaign column(without the _ ) is contained in product_group.

create table tablea(product_group varchar(50));

```
create table tableb(id_c int,campaign_month int, campaign varchar(50));

insert into tablea values('1808 Product - Group 3a')
insert into tablea values('1808 Product - Group 3b')
insert into tablea values('1808 Product - Group 1c - Test1')
insert into tablea values('1808 Product - Group 3s -1')
insert into tablea values('1808 Product - Group 4d')

insert into tablea values('1808 Product - Group 3a')
insert into tablea values('1808 Product - Group 3b')
insert into tablea values('1808 Product - Group 1c - Test1')
insert into tablea values('1808 Product - Group 3s -1')
insert into tablea values('1808 Product - Group 4d')

   select a.product_group, b.id_c,b.campaign_month,b.campaign
     from tablea a
left join tableb b
      on replace(a.product_group,' -',' ') like '%'+replace(b.campaign,'_',' ')+'%'
```

Demo link
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b1c19bc020e3a8a313ce78dd387f7c43

Comment: Hey @george
this is actually helpful. Though, the issue is, that the date is not being used to match the correct product_group. Also, I tried matching a campaign named `group_3s_1` to `product_group` which would be `1809 Product - Group 3s -1`. Do you have any suggestions on this?

Comment: The idea would be to compare by replace <space><hyphen> with a <space> in the column "product_group" and perform the comparison. I have updated the dbfiddle link and answer.I didnt follow the comment on "date not being used to match"?.